# How to stop a service when a button in the layout for another activity is pressed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service

I have a service that runs something every several seconds then sleeps until a certain time has elapsed. Not ideal, but effective for my purposes. I would like to have a button in the layout for NotifActivity start and stop the service called NotifService as requested. Here is basically what I have in NotifService:

```
public class NotifService extends IntentService {
public NotifService() {
    super("NotifService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    while(true){
        try {
            checkcalc();
            Thread.sleep(1000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Restore interrupt status.
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
 public void checkcalc () {
    //some code I am trying to run
}

public void notifSend(String num){

    //Sends a notification
    }
}
```

And the bit of NotifActivity that is called to start the service:

```
public void sendNotification(View view) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, NotifService.class);
    startService(serviceIntent);

}
```

How would I now stop the service? stopService(serviceIntent) seems ineffective, so what do I have to do.

Thanks!

Comment: "*stopService(serviceIntent) seems ineffective*"...why?

Comment: Putting that inside a method that is triggered by a button does not seem to stop the notification service, as I still receive notifications regularly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple workaround solution by making use of a volatile static variable and check continue condition in some of lines in your service that service continue should be checked:

```
class MyService extends IntentService {
public static volatile boolean shouldContinue = true;
public MyService() {
    super("My Service");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    doStuff();
}

private void doStuff() {
    // do something 

    // check the condition
    if (shouldContinue == false) {
          stopSelf();
          return;
      }

     // continue doing something

     // check the condition
     if (shouldContinue == false) {
         stopSelf();
         return;
     }

        // put those checks wherever you need
    }
}
```

and in your activity do this to stop your service,

```
MyService.shouldContinue = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

In `onHandleIntent()` you have this code:

```
while(true){
    try {
        checkcalc();
        Thread.sleep(1000);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // Restore interrupt status.
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

This will never stop running, as there is nothing to stop it from running. `IntentService` has started a worker-thread and this worker-thread has called `onHandleIntent()`. Even if you call `stopService()`, there is nothing that will stop the running worker-thread.

Your architecture is flawed. `IntentService` is not intended for this use. You should use `IntentService` when each call to `onHandleIntent()` will eventually complete.

You should just use a regular `Service` and override `onStartCommand()`. In `onStartCommand()` just create a `Handler` and post a `Runnable` that does what you want. At the end of this `Runnable`, the `Runnable` can post itself to the `Handler` using `postDelayed()`, which will run the `Runnable` again after a certain delay (instead of sleeping the thread). When you call `stopService()`, `onDestroy()` will be called in the `Service` and you should call `removeCallbacks()` to stop the `Runnable` from running again.

Answer (score 0):

> Not ideal, but effective for my purposes.

In the best-case scenario, your code will not work reliably. For example, it will not work when the device goes into sleep mode.

<sub>(the worst-case scenario involves angry users and guns)</sub>

Make sure that what you propose is *really* is [what the user will want](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/27/role-services.html).

> Here is basically what I have in NotifService:

`IntentService` is not designed for you to tie up its thread indefinitely. This is why you are having problems stopping it with `stopService()`.

> How would I now stop the service?

You would replace the service with your own `Service` subclass, with your own thread, that you kick off in `onStartCommand()`. Your UI would call `stopService()`, and in `onDestroy()`, you terminate that thread by one means or another.

For example, if you [used `ScheduledExecutorService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), instead of a `Thread.sleep()` loop, `onStartCommand()` would schedule your periodic job and `onDestroy()` would `shutdown()` the `ScheduledExecutorService`. You would not even need to mess with a thread, as `ScheduledExecutorService` provides one for the background work.